# how to configure Linux to use TCP for DNS queries?

Tags: domain-name-system

When I run my web crawler for 100,000 domains, a lot of DNS queries are made via UDP, and my ISP blocks my traffic thinking I am doing a DDoS attack. Is it possible to configure Linux to use TCP instead of UDP for DNS lookup queries? This needs to be done in a transparent way at the layer of GLIBC so I would not need to change the application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `use-vc` in `/etc/resolv.conf` (since glibc 2.14)

```
                Sets RES_USEVC in _res.options.  This option forces the
                 use of TCP for DNS resolutions.
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html

Comment: Sidenote: Simply add the line `options use-vc`